# how can I select a variable based on a number that the user inputs

Tags: python, class

I am trying to change the data in classes that I have created.
I have created 20 data sets (t1-20) with an empty field for the team name and score
I want to ask the user which team name/number they would like to edit, and then add their input into the list from the class 'AllTeams'

```
class AllTeams:
  def __init__(self, TeamNum, TeamName, TeamScore):
    self.TeamNum = TeamNum
    self.TeamName = TeamName
    self.TeamScore = TeamScore


  def myfunc(abc):
    print('Team Number:',abc.TeamNum,'|-|', 'Team Name:',abc.TeamName, '|-|', 'Team Score:',abc.TeamScore)


t1 = AllTeams(1, "N/A", 0)
t2 = AllTeams(2, "N/A", 0)
t3 = AllTeams(3, "N/A", 0)
t4 = AllTeams(4, "N/A", 0)
t5 = AllTeams(5, "N/A", 0)
t6 = AllTeams(6, "N/A", 0)
t7 = AllTeams(7, "N/A", 0)
t8 = AllTeams(8, "N/A", 0)
t9 = AllTeams(9, "N/A", 0)
t10 = AllTeams(10, "N/A", 0)
t11 = AllTeams(11, "N/A", 0)
t12 = AllTeams(12, "N/A", 0)
t13 = AllTeams(13, "N/A", 0)
t14 = AllTeams(14, "N/A", 0)
t15 = AllTeams(15, "N/A", 0)
t16 = AllTeams(16, "N/A", 0)
t17 = AllTeams(17, "N/A", 0)
t18 = AllTeams(18, "N/A", 0)
t19 = AllTeams(19, "N/A", 0)
t20 = AllTeams(20, "N/A", 0)#data for teams

t1.myfunc()
t2.myfunc()
t3.myfunc()
t4.myfunc()
t5.myfunc()
t6.myfunc()
t7.myfunc()
t8.myfunc()
t9.myfunc()
t10.myfunc()
t11.myfunc()
t12.myfunc()
t13.myfunc()
t14.myfunc()
t15.myfunc()
t16.myfunc()
t17.myfunc()
t18.myfunc()
t19.myfunc()
t20.myfunc()#printing the leaderboard of teams


TeamCounter=int(input('How many Teams will be in the tournament? '))
conversion=str(TeamCounter)
print('')
while TeamCounter>0:
    NameOfTeam=input('Please Enter Team Name: ')
    MemberCount=input('How Many Members in Team? ')
    TeamCounter-=1 #need this for the loop to work


NewTeam=('t'+conversion)
print(NewTeam)
```

Comment: Consider using a `list` instead of 20 separate variables for the teams

Comment: How could i go about doing this? @PranavHosangadi

Comment: `AllTeams` doesn't describe what that class does. It seems to represent *a* team in a collection, not *all* the teams in the collection.

Comment: Look up a tutorial on lists. "How can I use a list" is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: `teams = [AllTeams(i+1, "N/A", 0) for i in range(20)]`

Comment: Side note, in your `nyfunc` function, since it is now a member function, you should use `self` instead of `abc`.  That's not technically required, but it is a rigid convention that will make your life easier.  You might also consider making that the `__repr__` function, so you can just say `print(t1)` or `print(teams[0])`.

Comment: this can replace all the variables for team(t1-20)? @TimRoberts

Comment: Also consider changing the title of your question to what you are actually asking. You presumably already know how to set the value of an attribute of an object (Simply `t1.TeamName = "Blues"`). Your question seems to be "how can I select a variable based on a number that the user inputs". See [How do I create a variable number of variables](//stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/843953)

Comment: It will be `teams[0]` to `teams[19]`.  Remember Python numbers stuff from 0.

Comment: okay, looks alot neater. thankyou.
how would i actually change specific team names from this list? for example the user wants to change team names for t1, t2 and t3

Comment: You would access _that object in the list_ and then set its attribute to whatever you want it to be. This should be covered by any basic tutorial on lists (accessing items), and objects/classes (setting attributes). Please read [ask] and [how much research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953). Stack Overflow isn't a substitute for tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a summary of all of the comments so far.  Note that it's silly to create 20 teams, and then ask how many there will be.  This only creates the teams they ask for.  Also, you didn't have a place to put the number of players, so I'm not storing that.

```
class AllTeams:
  def __init__(self, TeamNum, TeamName, TeamScore):
    self.TeamNum = TeamNum
    self.TeamName = TeamName
    self.TeamScore = TeamScore

  def __repr__(self):
    return f'Team Number: {self.TeamNum} |-| Team Name: {self.TeamName} |-| Team Score: {self.TeamScore}'

#teams = [AllTeams(i+1, "N/A", 0) for i in range(20)]
teams = []

TeamCounter=int(input('How many Teams will be in the tournament? '))

print('')
for i in range(TeamCounter):
    NameOfTeam=input(f'Please Enter Team {i+1} Name: ')
    MemberCount=input('How Many Members in Team? ')
    teams.append( AllTeams( i+1, NameOfTeam, 0 ) )

for t in teams:
    print(t)
```

Output:

```
C:\tmp>python x.py
How many Teams will be in the tournament? 8

Please Enter Team 1 Name: abc
How Many Members in Team? 3
Please Enter Team 2 Name: def
How Many Members in Team? 3
Please Enter Team 3 Name: ghi
How Many Members in Team? 2
Please Enter Team 4 Name: jkl
How Many Members in Team? 9
Please Enter Team 5 Name: mno
How Many Members in Team? 3
Please Enter Team 6 Name: pqr
How Many Members in Team? 3
Please Enter Team 7 Name: stu
How Many Members in Team? 4
Please Enter Team 8 Name: vwx
How Many Members in Team? 3
Team Number: 1 |-| Team Name: abc |-| Team Score: 0
Team Number: 2 |-| Team Name: def |-| Team Score: 0
Team Number: 3 |-| Team Name: ghi |-| Team Score: 0
Team Number: 4 |-| Team Name: jkl |-| Team Score: 0
Team Number: 5 |-| Team Name: mno |-| Team Score: 0
Team Number: 6 |-| Team Name: pqr |-| Team Score: 0
Team Number: 7 |-| Team Name: stu |-| Team Score: 0
Team Number: 8 |-| Team Name: vwx |-| Team Score: 0

C:\tmp>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class is badly named because it only represents a single team - so I've renamed it.

I've added a repr for ease of printing.

There are a fixed number of teams. As someone else has said you should think about asking the user how many teams they want but I'll leave it as fixed for the purposes of demonstration.

```
class Team:
    def __init__(self, TeamNum, TeamName, TeamScore):
        self.TeamNum = TeamNum
        self.TeamName = TeamName
        self.TeamScore = TeamScore
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Team number: {self.TeamNum} |-| Team name: {self.TeamName} |-| Team score: {self.TeamScore}'
# construct a list of 20 teams
teams = [Team(n+1, 'N/A', 0) for n in range(20)]
# loop indefinitely until user inputs zero
while True:
    tnum = input('Enter team number (0 to end): ')
    try:
        # make sure the input is a number and also within range
        if (tnum := int(tnum)) == 0:
            break
        if tnum < 1 or tnum > len(teams):
            raise ValueError
        tname = input('Enter team name: ')
        # assign the input team name
        teams[tnum-1].TeamName = tname
        # print the modified team class
        print(teams[tnum-1])
    except ValueError:
        print(f'You need to enter a number between 1 and {len(teams)}')
# print all the teams
for team in teams:
    print(team)
```